# Can't connect to remote MySQL server (uses default server instead)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, debian

I'm trying to connect to an AWS MySQL server from my VPS, but no matter what I try, I just get access denied, my user has privileges to connect from any host.

If I try to connect via PHP:

```
$db = new mysqli('mysite.cufncdsjslka.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', 'my_user', 'my_pass', 'my_db');
```

Gives me: `Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'my_user'@'XXXX.myhost.com' (using password: YES) in /home/me/shopify/libraries/db.lib.php on line 4`

If I try to connect via the MySQL CLI:

```
mysql -h mysite.cufncdsjslka.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -umy_user -p
```

Gives me: 
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'my_user'@'xxxx.myhost.com' (using password: YES)`

This command works flawlessly on my PC, but not on my VPS.

I'm assuming it's some sort of security setting preventing MySQL from using external servers?

My VPS is running Debian squeeze with the LAMP components all from the standard Debian packages except for PHP which I manually updated to 5.4.

I'm posting this as a new question since most similar questions I've found on SO were a permissions issue (I've given my MySQL user priveliges to connect from any host) or a SELinux issue (which AFAIK doesn't apply to Debian)

Comment: You need to whitelist your IP or domain for remote mysql connections to work. This is usually found in your cpanel, under databases->remote mysql

Comment: Show us how you allowed it to connect from any host. Also, make sure to double check your password.

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe I'm able to connect from my own PC (via my localhost LAMP, my IDE or MySQL Workbench) without issues.

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe I ran: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db.* TO 'my_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;` via MySQL Workbench (which has no issues connecting to the MySQL server) which leads me to believe that it's an issue with my VPS connecting to the MySQL server, rather than a privilege on the MySQL server.

Comment: Doesn't that make a new user with no password? Use whatever you can to connect and take a look at your user table in your mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

OK.

I have seen this problem number of times for many different reasons. Since I cannot see your server or your logs so I am guessing from the information that there could be bind address issue.

In my.cnf check

```
bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP
```

change it to the the ipaddress of your mysql server for example 81.92.33.45

restart mysql after this. And if you are still unable to connect then let me know with the error info from log and I will look again.

Secondly make sure iptables are not causing problems.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```